# Pipe operator %>% error with seq() function in R

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe

I'm a big fan of the `%>%` operator from `magrittr`/`dplyr` and use it whenever possible. I'm having problems, however, using it to pipe to the `seq()` function.

As a trivial example, imagine I have a variable `x`, and I want to create a sequence from `x-5` to `x+5`. I could do it like this:

```
> x <- 10
> seq(from = x-5, to = x+5, by = 1)
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

But for the life of me I can't get it to work properly with piping. To demonstrate, let me sneak up on the problem a little bit. Assume `x <- 10`.

### Piping works in some situations ...

The following example silently pipes `10` to the `from` parameter and uses the `.`, along with some arithmetic, to set the `to` parameter to `15`, giving a sequence `10:15` as expected.

```
> x %>% seq(.+5)
[1] 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

I can explicitly set the `from` parameter as below, and it also gives the same, expected result (`10:15`):

```
> x %>% seq(from = ., to = .+5)
[1] 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

### But doesn't work in others ...

Now a little tweak on the previous example. I want to try to replicate my initial example and produce a sequence from `x-5` to `x+5`. I would expect that I could set the `from` parameter to `.-5`, but this does not give the expected result:

```
> x %>% seq(from = .-5, to = .+5)
[1]  5 15
```

It seems that the `from` and `to` are being correctly set to `5` and `15` respectively. But it appears that the `by` parameter has been set to `.` (i.e. `10`) to give the unexpected result `5 15` rather than the sequence `5:15`.

I can try to explicitly set the `by` parameter, but now I get an error:

```
> x %>% seq(from = .-5, to = .+5, by = 1)
Error in seq.default(., from = . - 5, to = . + 5, by = 1) : 
  too many arguments
```

You can see what it has done here, piping the `.` to the first parameter, but then it has my three explicit parameters to deal with also, and the error results.

**It worked fine right up until I wanted to do some arithmetic using `.` in the `from` parameter.**

Is there a way to do what I want to do, or is it just a fact of life that certain functions are not fully compatible with `%>%`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can prevent `%>%` from inserting . into the first argument by surrounding the right hand side with brace brackets:

```
10 %>% { seq(from = .-5, to = .+5) }
## [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Comment: Good Lord, was it that simple?! Thank you :)