# Piping in R :: Passing specific vector elements when feeding next function's arguments

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

Using piping in R (with `%>%`), how can one pass *specific* vector elements from a function's output to feed the next function's arguments?

I've tried using the dot operator with position in braces (i.e., `.[1], .[2]`) to no avail.

The only way that was working for me was with `sapply()`, but I'm wondering whether there's a simpler solution I'm missing.

### Example

```r
#I have a vector containing a sequence of numbers, with some duplicates and gaps, 
#and I want to use its start and end points to create an analogous consecutive sequence.

original_sequence <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 
43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 
58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 
73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87,
88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 98, 98, 99, 100, 101, 
102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110)

## unsuccessful attempt #1
original_sequence %>%
   range() %>% 
   seq()
[1] 1 2 ## this result is equivalent to the output of `seq(2)`, 
        ## but what I want is to compute `seq(1 ,110)`.


## unsuccessful attempt #2
original_sequence %>%
   range() %>% 
   seq(.[1]), .[2])

Error: unexpected ',' in:
"    range() %>% 
    seq(.[1]),"

## attempt #3: somewhat successful but I wonder whether there's a better way
original_sequence %>%
   range() %>% 
   sapply(., seq)

[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38
 [39]  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76
 [77]  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110
```

Bottom line -- I was able to do it with `sapply` but I hope to figure out a solution in the spirit of my second attempt, because it's more handy to know a universal way to cherry-pick the specific vector elements you want to pass to the next function's arguments.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47763028/pipe-operator-error-with-seq-function-in-r

Comment: `original_sequence %>% range %>% invoke(seq, .)` is maybe a tad more dplyr-y than your sapply version.

Comment: @JonSpring, the post you refer to is exactly on point, thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use `{}` and pass input arguments to `seq`

```
library(dplyr)

original_sequence %>%
  range() %>% 
  {seq(.[[1]], .[2])}

#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  11  12......
```

Or we can mix it with base R `do.call`

```
original_sequence %>% range() %>% {do.call(seq, as.list(.))}
```

Or as @Ozan147 mentioned if your sequence always starts with 1 we can use `max`

```
original_sequence %>% max %>% seq
```

Comment: Oh man, I was so close!

Comment: In addition to this generic solution, for sequences starting with 1; `original_sequence %>% max() %>% seq()` should be enough.

Comment: @RonakShah, the solution with `{}` is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `reduce`

```
library(tidyverse)
original_sequence %>% 
    range %>%
    reduce(seq)
#[1]   1   2   3   4   ...
```